# C++ containers' iterators

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

This question may sounds lame, but I haven't found clear answer. Can I assume, that iterator returned by `map`'s `find()` method will this points at the same data even if I'll add (or remove) other elements to the same `map`? It's unclear for me if `map`'s iterator points at position in `map` or at specific data...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can keep using the same iterator after `insert` or `erase` operations. The standard says (C++03 standard, Section 23.1.2, paragraph 8):

> The insert members shall not affect the validity of iterators and references to the container, and the erase
>   members shall invalidate only iterators and references to the erased elements.

This is true for all associative containers (`map`, `set`, `multimap`, `multiset`).

Comment: +1 for authoritative reference (here's another: http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Map.html).

Comment: Does it also try for TR1 containers such as unordered_map? I assume, that C++0x doesn't change iterator definition, because it cloud break compatibility?

Comment: @Goofy: You need to check the requirements for the specific containers you're interested in.  For example, the guarantee quoted above is also true for std::list, but not std::deque or std::vector.

Comment: @Goofy: `unordered_map` works differently. The `insert` operation may invalidate all iterators, but `erase` operation doesn't. Compatibility isn't an issue because `unordered_map` is not meant to be compatible with `map`.